# How to edit or cancel a Cognito Forms submission

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to edit or cancel a submitted response form? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

In [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can enable [Entry Sharing](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/entry-sharing), which allows forms to be edited after submission using secure links.  These links can be included on the confirmation page, sent in confirmation emails, and manually sent when managing entries.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/79/entries/sharing-entries

[image]